Is there a version of Weyl's unitary trick for positive characteristic?
One version of the unitary trick states that for a compact Lie group $G$ and representation $\rho: G \rightarrow GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ we can define $P = \int_G \rho(g)\rho(g)^*dg$ using the Haar measure, and find a principal square root $Q$ such that $Q^2 = P$. Then $\tau(g) = Q^{-1}\rho(g)Q$ is unitary.
Is there an analogue of this trick when the rep'n is over a field of positive characteristic? One can use the conjugation map $x \mapsto x^q$ over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$.

The unitary trick over $\mathbb{C}$ shows that every compact subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is conjugate to a subgroup of $U(n)$; this says that $U(n)$ is the maximal compact subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$.
Over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ we can still discuss the finite unitary group $U_n(\mathbb{F}_{q^2})$, which is a subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_{q^2})$. However, there is no analogue of the unitary trick, in the sense that we can't hope to conjugate an arbitrary subgroup $G$ of $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_{q^2})$ into the unitary group. This is because $G$ could be too large; for example it could be all of $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_{q^2})$ itself!
You might hope that at least we can conjugate a subgroup of, say, $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ into the unitary group. But this is still not possible; taking $n = 1$, the unitary group $U_1(\mathbb{F}_{q^2})$ can be identified with the kernel of the norm $N : \mathbb{F}_{q^2}^{\times} \to \mathbb{F}_q^{\times}$, which is cyclic of order $q + 1$. But $GL_1(\mathbb{F}_q) \cong \mathbb{F}_q^{\times}$ is cyclic of order $q - 1$. So the latter can't embed into the former for any $q \ge 4$. This counterexample even has order coprime to the characteristic so this isn't an issue with not being able to divide by $|G|$ either.
Over $\mathbb{C}$ the unitary trick crucially relies on the fact that averaging a bunch of inner products still produces an inner product; in particular, it still produces a bilinear map which is positive-definite, and hence nondegenerate. There is no analogue of positivity in positive characteristic and so no way to get a guarantee like this in positive characteristic; so even when we can divide by $|G|$, we can try to average an inner product over the action of $G$, but there's no reason the result should be nondegenerate, or even nonzero.

Thanks very much!
